# implement TextWatcher on multiple edittext fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have this application in which I create multiple EditTexts dynamically. The amount depends on user input. I am trying to allow the focus to change to the next edittext after two characters have been entered. I have this so far:

```
for(EditText editText : editTextList ) {

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if(s.toString().length() == 2) {
                    //code to change focus to next edit text goes here
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

The first problem is that this could potentially create many instances of TextWatcher if the user enters a large number (average in this context would probably be 100-600 EditText fields).

The second problem is how would I go about changing focus in the afterTextChanged method because I would want to change the focus to the next EditText away from the one that is currently being represented inside the loop.

Should I not be concerned about the potential performance issues of multiple TextWatcher objects? Should I scrap this whole implementation and focus elsewhere? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For multiple instance problem create a single textwatcher object outside the loop and set that to all edittext in the loop

Answer (score 0):

**As you may have a lot of EditTexts at runtime** i would suggest you to use **maxlength** attribute of EditText in this way you will restrict user to enter only 2 characters.

like this

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
int maxLength = 2;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

Now **add next button** in your keyboard like this

```
yourEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

It is the default behavior of next button to change focus to the immediate next view which takes input being in the same parent layout.

Comment: I was already using editText,setMaxEms(2)to limit character input to 2. The next button is actually going down instead of to the right but that is because of the way they were created. My goal is to allow the user enter 12 straight digits and subsequently have 6 edittext fields filled out. This is just a convenience issue to make it easier on the user having to populate many fields.

Comment: Okay, i have figured out what you exactly need. so coming to defining click listener in a loop is a bad idea you should not implement click listener in this way. Text change listener consists of 3 overridden methods so each time your listener gets define *3 methods will be called automatically which is not a good approach.